# Zend Cache is not retrieving cache items after some period of time

Tags: zend-framework, caching

I am using Zend Cache with page caching but it seems to miss the cache after a period of time. For a while it is OK, but I come back tomorrow and hit the page, it doesn't fetch the contents from the cache. why?

```
$frontendOptions = array(
    'content_type_memorization' => true, // This remembers the headers, needed for images
   'lifetime' => NULL,                   // cache lifetime forever
   'automatic_serialization' => true,
   'automatic_cleaning_factor' => 0
);

$myPageCache = new Zend_Cache_Frontend_Page(array(
    'debug_header' => false,
    'automatic_cleaning_factor'=>0,
    'content_type_memorization' => true,
    'default_options'           => array(
    'cache' => true,
    'cache_with_get_variables' => true,
    'cache_with_post_variables' => true,
    'cache_with_session_variables' => true,
    'cache_with_cookie_variables' => true
    )));


$backendOptions = array('cache_dir' => '.' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cache' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

$cache = Zend_Cache::factory($myPageCache,
                             'File',
                             $frontendOptions,
                             $backendOptions);

$cacheKey = hash('md5', "cache_" . $cachePath); // cachePath is the key I use for the cache

if(!$cache->start($cacheKey)) {
I output html here
 $cache->end();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed. My read of the static method

```
Zend_Cache::factory($frontend, $back, $frontendOptions, $backendOptions, ...)
```

is that the `$frontendOptions` are used only when you pass a string for the `$frontend` parameter. When you pass a concrete instance as you are doing, the `$frontendOptions`  are ignored.

If you still want to pass a concrete instance `$myPageCache` into the factory, then it seems like you need to pass the lifetime parameter (and the others) into the call that creates the instance. Otherwise, you could load up a single `$frontendOptions` array and use:

```
$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Page', 'File', $frontendOptions, $backendOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

ahh... opps.

Is it because my 'lifetime' => NULL,        is being ignored?